# iptables command is not accepted in parrot OS

Tags: linux, iptables, syntax, parrotsec

I created my own chain called `test`. I want to insert a new rule in the chain that drops all packets to an IP address at a specified port.

```
sudo iptables -I test -j DROP -d 130.x.y.z -dport 24
```

The parrot OS VM  tells me that it doesn't know the argument `24` in the above command. I have been trying this for like 2 hours and still haven't gotten anywhere.

```
-I inserts a rule
-j specifies the action to the packet in the rule
-d specifies the destination which should be an IP address and not a name
-dport should be the port # for which this firewall rule should act
```

I have tried many variations such as `--destination` or `--destination-port`

Not sure how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your syntax is incorrect, try the following:

To block all traffic

```
iptables -I test -j DROP -d 130.x.y.z -p all
```

To block a specific port like ssh(22)

```
iptables -I test -j DROP -d 130.x.y.z -p tcp --dport 22
```

where -p is the protocol tcp or udp and --dport is the destination port

Comment: WOW thank you so much.  Worked great.

Comment: Heysus Escobar, Why is it that all other arguments in the iptables command. need one dash in front of the argument letter such as -j , -I , -p, but the min phrase, --dport needs two dashes in front.  Is it because its not a single letter argument so the syntax rule is implemented as two dashes to  differentiate between the arguments as its executed????